# Is there an API for searching the US Copyright database?

Tags: api

I was pointed to this StackExchange from Twitter --  I'm wondering if there's any kind of stable/published API for accessing the Copyright data exposed over [here](http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi).

As it is, it's not incredibly difficult to grab with curl or parse with `beautifulsoup`, but it's not clear if there's a TOS for searching, or if the site is friendly to bots.

Thanks for any info you can provide!

Comment: I have not heard of any APIs at the Library of Congress (LOC). Have you contacted the copysearch@loc.gov team or the webmaster copyweb@loc.gov ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the information from their OData Site:

http://id.loc.gov/techcenter/

they mention you can curl it, but apparently RDF-a (

> Rendering the XHTML source for a given concept or heading through a
>   RDFa-aware processing tool, such as the RDFa Distiller offered by the
>   W3C. For example, "Bahia grass", when processed by the RDFa distiller,
>   yields this result.

) is an option, traditional crawling/scraping (ugh), and they also mention wget, and Perl: LWP::UserAgent, Java: HttpClient, Python: httplib.

Also from that site, if you use the breadcrumbs under Technical Center, it provides format types, metadata types, Search/query options (you can apparently also use OpenQuery on their site when on a modern browser, [I did not try this] (If you don't know about this, look it up [OpenSearch.org](http://www.opensearch.org/Home), it is pretty sweet) and serialization options.

> Supported RDF MIME types and serialization formats
>
> RDF Data returned from the Linked Data Service can be serialized in
>   several formats. •RDF/XML (MIME type: application/rdf+xml; Extension:
>   .rdf) Example •N-Triples (MIME type: text/plain; Extension: .nt)
>   Example •Javascript Object Notation (MIME type: application/json;
>   Extension: .json) Example •JSON-P (JSON) (Extension: .jsonp; accepts
>   "callback" query string parameter) Example •XHTML + RDFa 1.0 (MIME
>   type: application/xhtml+xml; Extension: .html) Example
>
> Supported Search serialization formats
>
> Search results from the Linked Data Service can be serialized in
>   several formats. •XHTML (Default setting)  •ATOM (XML)( (add query
>   string parameter: "format=atom") Example •JSONML (JSON) (add query
>   string parameter: "format=json") Example •JSON-P (JSON) (add query
>   string parameter: "format=jsonp"; also acccepts "callback" query
>   string parameter) Example